# Phaser 3 how to change gravity when the player jumps

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am developing an arcade game in Phaser 3, the problem is that the player sprite is dropped from the top of the screen when the game loads and I don't want that, I want him to be rendered without falling so I set the y gravity to 0 in order to achieve that. That works, however now my player cannot jump, I am trying to reset the gravity to 300 on keyDown but that isn't working, how can I achieve that? I tried to set the y gravity to 300 again in the create function but that didn't work too is it possible?

Here is my code:

```
// let gravity = 0

let config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 500,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 0 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    },
    scale: {
     mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
     parent: 'root',
     autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
     width: 800,
     height: 600
 },
 };
 
 
 new Phaser.Game(config)


 function preload() {
 
 this.load.image('sky', require('../assets/backgrounds/sky.png'));
 this.load.image('jungle', require('../assets/backgrounds/jungle.png'));
 
 this.load.image('ground', require('../assets/tiles/ground-transp.png'))
 this.load.image('small-platform', require("../assets/tiles/small-platform-removebg-preview.png"))
 this.load.image('jungle-platform', require("../assets/tiles/jungle-platform.png"))
 this.load.image('large-platform', require("../assets/tiles/large-platform-removebg-preview.png"))
 this.load.image('tree', require("../assets/backgrounds/treetrunk.png"))
 this.load.image('plant', require("../assets/backgrounds/plant.png"))
 this.load.image('plant2', require("../assets/backgrounds/plants2.png"))
 this.load.image('rock', require("../assets/backgrounds/rock.png"))

 this.load.atlas('sacred', require('../assets/spritesheets/sacredRock.png'), require('../assets/spritesheets/sacredRock.json'))
 this.load.atlas('player', require('../assets/spritesheets/dilopodon.png'), require('../assets/spritesheets/dilopodon.json'))

 this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('Ground', require('../assets/maps/simple-tutorial.json'));
 
 }
 
 function create () {
 
 this.bg = this.add.image(-41, -41, 'sky');
 this.bg = this.add.image('jungle');
 this.add.image(67, 370, 'tree')
 this.add.image(167, 429, 'plant')
 this.add.image(700, 405, 'plant2')
 this.add.image(300, 440, 'rock')
 
 const map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'Ground' })
 
 // Creating tilesets

 const groundTileSet = map.addTilesetImage('Ground', 'ground')
 const platformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('small-platform', 'small-platform')
 const junglePlatformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('jungle-platform', 'jungle-platform')
 const largePlatformTileset = map.addTilesetImage('large-platform', 'large-platform')
 
 let groundLayer = map.createLayer('Ground', [groundTileSet, platformTileset, junglePlatformTileset, largePlatformTileset])
 groundLayer.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);
 

 
 // Creating the Player
 
 player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 420, 'player')
 player.setBounce(0.2);
 player.setCollideWorldBounds(true)

 player.body.width = 60
 player.body.height = 60
 player.body.offset.x = 10
 player.body.offset.x = 10



 // Creating the Sacred Stone

 sacredStone = this.physics.add.sprite(400, 270, 'sacred')
 sacredStone.setCollideWorldBounds(true)

 sacredStone.body.width = 60
 sacredStone.body.height = 230

 //Physics
 this.physics.add.collider(groundLayer, player )
 this.physics.add.collider(groundLayer, sacredStone )

 // Debug graphics
// let graphics = this.add.graphics()
// groundLayer.renderDebug(graphics, {
//     tileColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(0, 0, 255, 50), // Non-colliding tiles
//     collidingTileColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(0, 255, 0, 100), // Colliding tiles
//     faceColor: new Phaser.Display.Color(255, 0, 0, 100) // Colliding face edges
// });

 
//  let frameNames = this.textures.get('player').getFrameNames();


 function update() {

    sacredStone.anims.play('glow', true)


    if (cursors.left.isDown)
{
    player.setVelocityX(-160);

    player.anims.play('walkLeft', true);
}
else if (cursors.right.isDown)
{
    player.setVelocityX(160);

    player.anims.play('walkRight', true)
    
}
else
{
    player.setVelocityX(0);

    player.anims.play('idle', true);
}

if (cursors.up.isDown && player.body.blocked.down)
{   
    config.physics.arcade.gravity.y = 300
    player.setVelocityY(-330);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, that when you set the position of the `player` in the game, you are setting it to low. When two **gameObject** within arcade physics **overlap**, they can't collide anymore, so they fall through.

I would set the gravity again, and than just set the position of the `player` just a few pixels higher `-10` might be enough. If it still falls through set it higher until it works. I think the `sacredStone` has the same issue.